# Why is an object different than the same object destructured?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was working with a library that needs a configuration object with a couple of properties inside of it... I realized that `{...object}` is not the same as `object`, I tried to understand why but even after debbuging and logging those objects, I can't see not difference at all on them:

```js
const configurationObject = {
  name: 'name',
  uniqueId: 'random-string'
}

//...

const object1 = configurationObject
const object2 = {...configurationObject}

console.log(object1 == object2) // false

const object3 = configurationObject
const object4 = configurationObject

console.log(object3 == object4) // true

const object5 = {...configurationObject}
const object6 = {...configurationObject}

console.log(object5 == object6) // false
```

I just realized that:

1. `object1` and `object2` are **not** the same
2. `object3` and `object4` **are** the same
3. `object5` and `object6` are **not** the same

Can someone explain why that happens? I tought about it being related to different memory adresses, but that wouldn't make much sense since `object5` and `object6` are not the same also.

Also, if that's related to memory address, can someone tell me how to access, via node, the memory address? Or at least something that tells me both objects are different.

Comment: The syntax `{`…`}` creates a new object. _“but that wouldn't make much sense since `object5` and `object6` are not the same also”_ — Exactly. They are not the same. Those are two new objects.

Comment: But does the content changes also? In any way or form?
Because:
1. new ServiceBusClient('connectionString', obj1) => This fails
2. new ServiceBusClient('connectionString', {...obj1}) => This works

Comment: Why one thing fails and the other succeeds entirely depends on what `ServiceBusClient` is doing; there could be countless reasons, including bad API design. The content isn’t different and needn’t be different: `({ a: 1 }) !== ({ a: 1 })` (same content, different reference).

Comment: this question is touches an interesting and really important topic, but doesn't belong to SO in my opinion - not a specific (reproducible) problem, not a debugging issue, but a question about how JS objects work. [Possible source on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals) ("shallow cloning").

Answer (score 1):

Doing `object1 === object2` does not check if the two variables reference objects that contain the same properties. It checks if both variables reference the same object instance.

The line `const object2 = {...configurationObject}` creates a new object instance containing a shallow copy of the properties in `object1`. Therefore, it is a different object instance.

```js
const configurationObject = {
  name: 'name',
  uniqueId: 'random-string'
}

//...

const object1 = configurationObject
const object2 = {...configurationObject}

console.log(object1 === object2) // false
console.log(JSON.stringify(object1) === JSON.stringify(object2)) // true

const object3 = configurationObject
const object4 = configurationObject

console.log(object3 === object4) // true
console.log(JSON.stringify(object3) === JSON.stringify(object4)) // true

const object5 = {...configurationObject}
const object6 = {...configurationObject}

console.log(object5 === object6) // false
console.log(JSON.stringify(object5) === JSON.stringify(object6)) // true
```